# cakephp view will not display

Tags: cakephp

I have an order form to purchse a voucher but for some reason now when I click phurcase it displays a blank screen. I cant see what has changed and why the view is not being passed the information from the controller.

Vourchers form

```
        <h2>Vouchers</h2>

        <?php   
                foreach($vouchers as $v){
        ?>


            <div id="voucher_box" class="add_shadow column span-8">

                <h3><?=$v['Voucher']['title'];?></h3>

                <p>
                    <?=$v['Voucher']['description'];?>
                </p>

            <?php 
                echo $this->Form->create('Voucher',array('id'=>'ResVoucherForm','url'=>'/res/voucher'));
                echo $this->Form->input('slug',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$v['Voucher']['slug']));
            ?>  

                <select id="VoucherPrice" name="data[Voucher][price]">
                <? $prices = explode(',',$v['Voucher']['prices'])?>

                <? foreach($prices as $price){?>
                    <option value="<?=$price?>">&euro; <?=$price?></option>
                <? } ?>
                </select>

                <div class="submit"><input type="submit" id="check_rates" value="Purchase this" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /></div>

                </form>

            </div>



        <?
                }
        ?>
```

Controller

```
function voucher() {
    $this->layout = '360';

    $msg[0] = array(); // 0 = bad messages
    $msg[1] = array(); // 1 = good messages

    $total_price = 0.00;

    if(isset($data['Voucher'])) { $this->data['Voucher'] = $data['Voucher']; }

    if(isset($this->data['Voucher'])) {

        // if we have posted a voucher purchase: add it to session array
        if(isset($this->data['Voucher']['slug'])){

            $slug = $this->data['Voucher']['slug'];
            $voucher = $this->getVoucher($slug);

            $voucher['Voucher']['price'] = $this->data['Voucher']['price'];

            $vouchers = $this->Session->read('Res.Vouchers'); // read existing voucher orders

            if(is_array($vouchers) && isset($voucher['Voucher'])){

                $temp['id']             = $voucher['Voucher']['id'];
                $temp['title']          = $voucher['Voucher']['title'];
                $temp['description']    = $voucher['Voucher']['description'];
                $temp['slug']           = $voucher['Voucher']['slug'];
                $temp['price']          = $this->data['Voucher']['price'];

                $vouchers[] = $temp;
            }

            $this->Session->write('Res.Vouchers',$vouchers);
        } else {
            $vouchers = $this->Session->read('Res.Vouchers'); // read existing voucher orders
        }   

        $this->set('voucher_orders', $vouchers);
    }
```

This next view displays blank, I do not know how to test the information in the controller

```
            <?php
            /*
                if voucher show
            */

                if (isset($voucher)) { 

            ?>
                    <div id="voucher_box" class="add_shadow column span-8">

                        <h3><?=$voucher['Voucher']['title'];?></h3>

                        <p>
                            <?=$voucher['Voucher']['description'];?>
                        </p>

                    <?php 
                        echo $this->Form->create('Voucher',array('id'=>'ResVoucherForm','url'=>'/res/voucher'));
                        echo $this->Form->input('slug',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$voucher['Voucher']['slug']));
                    ?>  

                        <select id="VoucherPrice" name="data[Voucher][price]">
                        <? $prices = explode(',',$voucher['Voucher']['prices'])?>

                        <? foreach($prices as $price){?>
                            <option value="<?=$price?>">&euro; <?=$price?></option>
                        <? } ?>
                        </select>

                        <div class="submit"><input type="submit" id="check_rates" value="Purchase this" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /></div>

                        </form>

                    </div>
            <?
                } 
                // end if voucher show
            ?>
```

Upadate Error Returned #######################################################

Notice (8): Undefined index: id [APP/controllers/res_controller.php, line 739]

Notice (8): Undefined index: title [APP/controllers/res_controller.php, line 740]

Notice (8): Undefined index: description [APP/controllers/res_controller.php, line 741]

Notice (8): Undefined index: slug [APP/controllers/res_controller.php, line 742]

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [slug] => 
            [price] => 100
        )

)

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled? If not set debug to 2 in your core.php and check the error output. You can also make outputs in your controller using the pr() or debug() functions like pr($this->data) for instance

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am very unsure about testing data in conrollers. I have done a pr($vouchers) under the $this->set('voucher_orders', $vouchers);. I have posted the error, I dont see what is wrong as it was fine before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. By using the pr() or debug() in the controller I found the problem. It was in the function that was getting called on the line $voucher = $this->getVoucher($slug);. I now have a better understanding of cakephp.

Answer (score 2):

In the view, you have this around the whole HTML:

```
if (isset($voucher)) {
    // ...
}
```

Meaning: display voucher information if there is a voucher, and do not display anything otherwise.

Now, in your controller, you don't seem to be passing a `voucher` variable to the view (which should be done with `$this->set('varname', $var)`;

So, your view does not get any data, thus it does not display anything.

This could explain your issue. But if the screen is completely blank (not even the layout displays), then you must enable error logging to check what's going on.

Comment: I do have $this->set('voucher_orders', $vouchers);
in the controller is this what you mean? Thanks

Comment: The way you have it, the variable name on the view will be `$voucher_orders`, not `$voucher`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `'voucher_orders'` to your view not `'voucher'` the name of the variable in the view is always the string passed in the set method. Also I don't quite understand what you are doing in the controller with the `$data` variable, where does it come from? Also it's redundant doing `$this->data['Voucher'] = $data['Voucher']` and the checking `$this->data` isset if you already checked if `$data` is set. You might be overwriting your `$this->data` array, what you are doing is not necessary since the view already gives you a populated `$this->data` if its a form submission.

You should really try doing some tutorials and reading up a little before jumping in, you seem to not properly understand the CakePHP structure and workflow.

Comment: I have had this app developed for me. I have a limit knowlegeof php and none in cakephp. What I am looking for is a developer to go through the code because I can see that it is not structured correctly. It does work with some minor issues but was developed in quickly because of money constraints. I would be interested if anyone knows of a good cakephp company.

Comment: When I do a pr($voucher_orders); at the end of the controller I get Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => [title] => [description] => [slug] => [price] => 100 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => [title] => [description] => [slug] => [price] => 50 ) ) and undefined index for the temp avriables.

Comment: Because in the controller $voucher_orders doesn't exist, what exists is $vouchers